# Using regex in Javascript to replace a part of the string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have some text I am trying to replace a part of with regex in Angularjs.

The text will be in the format:

```
Name: Jane
Age: 66
Address: 31 Test Street
```

I would like to replace the part after Age: with 'REDACTED' (so 66 will not appear), so I have created this filter which to me seems like it should work:

```
angular.module('person')
    .controller(controllerId, personControl)
.filter('ageFilter', function () {
    return function (text) {
        if (text)
            return text.replace(/[\n\r].*Age: \s*([^\n\r]*)/, 'REDACTED');
        return '';
    }
});
```

The relevant part of the html:

```
<dd ng-bind-html="vm.model.PERSON_INFO | ageFilter"></dd>
```

The filter is hit but the text is never replaced. My regex works when I test on Regex test websites, so I think I may be doing something else wrong which I cannot see.

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces issue

Comment: Just a pointer, should you not assign the return value so that it is reflected in view?

Comment: I think that problem is with your text, will it have \n in it?

Comment: Shouldn't `text.replace(/^(Age:[\t ]*).*/m, '$1REDACTED');` suffice? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrF6EW/1). BTW, [your regex does not work well](https://regex101.com/r/PMunDR/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return text.replace(/([\n\r]+.*Age: )(\s*)([^\n\r]*)/, '$1REDACTED$2')
```